# Random jQuery for Cordova App

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have a problem with my jQuery Code
I want to randomize numbers in a range and I wrote this:
jQuery Code:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  var numLow = $("#lownumber").value();
  var numHigh = $("#highnumber").value();
  var adjustedHigh = (parseFloat(numHigh) - parseFloat(numLow)) + 1;
  var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * adjustedHigh) + parseFloat(numLow);
  if ((isFinite(numLow)) && (isFinite(numHigh)) && parseFloat(numLow) <= parseFloat(numHigh) && (numLow != '') && (numHigh != '')) {
    $("#random").text(numRand);
  } else {
    $("#random").text("Ops... an error!");
  }
  return false;
});
```

HTML page:

```
<body>
  <div class="text">Random</div>
  <input type="text" id="lownumber" value="1">
  <input type="text" id="highnumber" value="100">
  <input type="submit" id="button" value="Generate!">
  <div id="random"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/random.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

PLEASE HELP ME! T.T

Comment: What problems did you run in to?  Please be specific in your questions.

Comment: IcarusFox did my anwser help?

Comment: Thank you Amanuel, finally it works :3

Answer (score 1):

It is suppose to be `.val()` Not `.value()` So now it works..

```js
$("#button").click(function(){

var numLow = $("#lownumber").val();
var numHigh = $("#highnumber").val();
var adjustedHigh = (parseFloat(numHigh) - parseFloat(numLow))+1;
var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random()*adjustedHigh)+parseFloat(numLow);
if((isFinite(numLow)) && (isFinite(numHigh)) && parseFloat(numLow) <= parseFloat(numHigh) && (numLow != '') && (numHigh != '')){
    $("#random").text(numRand);
} else {
    $("#random").text("Ops... an error!");
}
return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="text">Random</div>
<input type="text" id="lownumber" value="1">
<input type="text" id="highnumber" value="100">
<input type="submit" id="button" value="Generate!">
<div id="random"></div>

</body>
```